# Translate rangeOfString from Objective-c To Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsrange

I'm trying for hours to translate this short code.
Objective C :

```
NSString *urlStr = [request.URL absoluteString];
NSArray *urlParts = [urlStr componentsSeparatedByString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/", kREDIRECTURI]];

if (urlParts.count > 1)
{
    urlStr = urlParts[1];
    NSRange token = [urlStr rangeOfString:@"#access_token="];

    if (token.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        vc.access_token = [urlStr substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange(token)];
    }
}
```

What i have tried :

Swift :

```
var urlParts : NSArray = urlStr!.componentsSeparatedByString("\(kREDIRECTURI)")
if urlParts.count > 1
{
    urlStr = urlParts[1] as? String
    var token  = urlStr!.rangeOfString("#access_token=", options: NSStringCompareOptions.allZeros) as NSRange!

    if token != nil
    {
         var vc = ViewController()
         urlStr!.substringFromIndex(NSMaxRange(token))!
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: What isn't working? One small point is that you are not setting vc.access_token in the swift code.

Comment: @Bijington I just removed that line because i know how to translate the rest lol , i just wanted to show less code. the line that i cannot resolve is :      NSArray *urlParts = [urlStr componentsSeparatedByString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/", kREDIRECTURI]];
 and

Comment: @Bijington                 vc.access_token = [urlStr substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange(token)];

Comment: You can't cast Range to NSRange in this line.
    var token  = urlStr!.rangeOfString("#access_token=", options: NSStringCompareOptions.allZeros) as NSRange!

Comment: @EpicByte ya i know , im trying to find the right way.

Comment: @roimulia Do you need to use NSRange? Why don't you just use the Swift Range?

Comment: actually I'm translating the code that is working(the objective c part), im just trying to copy it as needed so it will work

Comment: @roimulia If you cast your string to NSString then you will get an NSRange instead of a Range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the access_token query parameter is at the end and the code follows the string like this 'http:\...#access_token=', the url ends with the code at the end. Here is a simple method that would extract the code out of the url,

```
func getTokenFromUrl(url: String) -> String? {

    let range1 = url.rangeOfString("#access_token")

    guard let range = range1 else { return nil }

    let startIndex = range.endIndex.successor()
    let rangeOfToken = url.endIndex

    let rangeOfString = startIndex ..< rangeOfToken

   return  url.substringWithRange(rangeOfString)
}

let url1 = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010975/translate-rangeofstring-from-objective-c-to-swift?#access_token=873jasf82jmsa8sd"

let url2 = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010975/translate-rangeofstring-from-objective-c-to-swift"

getTokenFromUrl(url1) // returns 873jasf82jmsa8sd
getTokenFromUrl(url2) // returns nil
```

For earlier version of Swift, you could use if let patter to unwrap the optional,

```
func getTokenFromUrl(url: String) -> String? {

    let range1 = url.rangeOfString("#access_token")

    if let range = range1 {

        let startIndex = range.endIndex.successor()
        let rangeOfToken = url.endIndex

        let rangeOfString = startIndex ..< rangeOfToken

       return  url.substringWithRange(rangeOfString)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: @roimulia Please see my changes.

Comment: return  url1.substringWithRange(rangeOfString)
does the url1 suppose to be url? :D

Comment: Yes indeed ! Corrected :)

Comment: Seems to be working!! :) Just if you can please provide me an asnwer, how should i arrange the code from the OP if im using this method instead of the Objective C method?

Comment: I dont get it. Do you mean that you want to write it in Objective C and call that method from Swift.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81326/discussion-between-roi-mulia-and-generatorofone).